# Email and telephone identification - gmail

Tags: email

I was advised to post this as a new question, so linking from my previous question ([Tracing senders](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169175/tracing-senders?noredirect=1#comment322897_169175)) and the exchanges there, I have been doing some further work this morning and I have one further question. When examining the email on gmail (using the 'original email' link) where can you find information about the mobile telephone that was used to send the email? 
Thanks again,
Andrew.

Comment: Which part in the answers or comments in the question you refer to makes you think that this should be possible? As far as I can see they refer to information the mobile provider might have - which is not the same as the email provider. Thus, no information in the email.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I have done the following:

Comment: Sorry! Pressed return and it sent my last comment....I have done the following: 1. I sent an email from my telephone using 4g and then wifi. 2. I then opened up the details about the emails and compared them. I can see differences clearly because of how the email was communicated, but I can't seem to understand what about the 4G would reveal about the sender...there is no mobile telephone number and the phones imie isn't anywhere to be found. Surely there is something about the contract or an identifier...Can an email be identified as coming from a specific phone or a mobile monthly contract?

Comment: If I am being a nuisance with my questions, please just say! I'm sorry if I'm being ignorant re tech etc but I'm not clued up on this at all and I'm trying to get up to speed on the basics. I'm happy to pay someone a consultation fee if that helps and to give them a mention in the book (for which I have a publisher) Cheers.

Comment: I dont understand the question at all but you can use some services to track the sender. I am using http://whatismyipaddress.com/email-header but you can search as well for tools on market.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich actually, not a dupe, but rather "unclear what you're asking" if you think it's a dupe :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you might refer to this passage in my answer to your question, rather than the comment you linked to:

> Much more plausible would be to ask the email provider for data on previous or subsequent usage of the account. If it gets accessed over the mobile network and the provider has logs of its NAT, the phone may be tracked.

There are several steps here that are to be taken, none has anything to do with email headers. Given, sometimes information is leaked through email headers; yet, let's assume they use a webmailing service with fake information. No information is leaked about the sender then.

Yet, as described in my previous answer:

If

- the Email-Provider can give information on IP addresses previously or subsequently accessing this account and
- the mobile network provider that those IP addresses belong to has traffic logs and logs of its NATs,

there might be a possibility that the actual user of the email address can be tracked.

Still, both points are big **if**s and pretty unlikely to happen,

For the first case, because the user might never again use and never previously used that account and there are few legal ways to track that information.

For the second case, because the data neccessary for that is **huge** and again, legal reasons.